# Appending to lists inside ADT

Tags: rascal

I am trying to append to a list inside an ADT as follows:

```
data MyADT = myadt(list[str] s); 
m = myadt([]);
m.s += "test";
```

Which causes an error:

```
|prompt:///|(0,3,<1,0>,<1,3>): Expected list[str], but got str
?[Advice](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UnexpectedType/UnexpectedType.html)
```

Which seems like it should work because this works:

```
x = [];
x += "test";
```

Maybe I am missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a workaround:

```
rascal>m.s += ["test"];
MyADT: myadt(["test"])
```

It looks like a bug.

By the way we will remove the overloading of + to add both elements and concatenate lists and introduce a special operator for adding elements. It's confusing as it is now.

Comment: Just typing `m.s = m.s + "test"` should also work fine, most likely this is an issue with computing the type given a void container (although I'm surprised Rascal thinks it's void given it has an explicit type declaration).

Comment: Thanks! I had come to this workaround already and thought I tried the second one as well but I guess I didn't.